# Resources for Gravitational Soliton (specially on the Belinski–Zakharov transform)

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, solitons

Can someone provide some resources (books, notes, articles etc.) on [Gravitational Soliton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_soliton) (specially on the [Belinski–Zakharov transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinski%E2%80%93Zakharov_transform))?

I've found only the following two reference from the Wikipedia references:

1. Belinskii, V.; Zakharov, V. $(1978)$. "Integration of the Einstein Equations by Means of the Inverse Scattering Problem Technique and Construction of Exact Soliton Solutions". Sov. Phys. JETP. $48~(6):~985–994$. ISSN [$0038-5646$](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=n2:0038-5646).
2. Belinski, V.; Verdaguer, E. ($2001$). Gravitational Solitons. Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics.

I'm searching for a few more.

**NOTE:** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinski%E2%80%93Zakharov_transform) is saying,

> The Belinski–Zakharov (inverse) transform is a nonlinear transformation that generates new exact solutions of the vacuum Einstein's field equation. It was developed by Vladimir Belinski and Vladimir Zakharov in $1978$.$^{[1]}$ The Belinski–Zakharov transform is a generalization of the inverse scattering transform. The solutions produced by this transform are called gravitational solitons (gravisolitons).

Answer (score 1):

For the details of the Belinski–Zakharov transform I would recommend this paper of theirs, published the year following the one you already found:

- V.A. Belinskii, V.E. Zakharov, Stationary gravitational solitons with axial symmetry, Sov. Phys. JETP, 50(1), 1-9, (1979)

It can be hard to find PDFs of these papers, and honestly best place I have found to get them is on this conference website: [zakharov75.itp.ac.ru/zve75/tt/publications](http://zakharov75.itp.ac.ru/zve75/tt/publications).

Starting in the early 2000s their methods were generalized to higher dimensions, to reproduce Myers-Perry black holes, construct black saturn solutions, etc. Many of those newer papers have nice reviews of inverse scattering methods in GR (e.g. the Belinski–Zakharov transform). See for example

- arXiv:hep-th/0507250
- arXiv:hep-th/0701035

The book "[Exact Solutions of Einstein's Field Equations](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/exact-solutions-of-einsteins-field-equations/generation-techniques/AD4DC0F065DF8005BF3480CCF9D10894)" also tends to be a great reference for solution generating methods in GR.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).